# Determine number of common rows (or exact intersection of rows) from two dataframe python (with exception case)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I am trying to get the exact intersection of rows between two pandas df in python. I am able to do it with the help of `merge()` function.

Current logic:

```
import pandas as pd

# input df's
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[1,2,3,4,5,3],                   
                      'x3':[9,8,7,6,6,8]})

data3 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[2,1,2,6,4,4,5],                   
                      'x3':[8,3,9,8,7,6,6]})


data_13 = data1.merge(data3,                                  # Merge DataFrames with indicator 
                        indicator = True,
                        how = 'outer')
print(data_13)                                               

## common rows (the appears in both data1 and data3)
data_13_diff = data_13.loc[lambda x : x['_merge'] == 'both'] 
print(data_13_diff)   
                                        
## count the number of rows in data_13_diff
print('count:',data_13_diff.shape[0])
```

Output:

```
   x1  x3 _merge
1   2   8   both
3   4   6   both
4   5   6   both
count: 3
```

As expected, the output shows the common rows (intersecting rows) in both data1 and data3

However, stuck at this exception when there are multiple same value rows in one df.
For example:

```
# input df's
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[1,2,3,4,5,2],                    
                      'x3':[9,8,7,6,6,8]})

data3 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[1,2,2,4,4,5,3],                   
                      'x3':[3,9,8,7,6,6,8]})
```

The output comes to be:

```
   x1  x3 _merge
1   2   8   both
2   2   8   both
4   4   6   both
5   5   6   both
count: 4
```

even though there is only one instance of (2,8) in data3, the current logic outputs 2 such instances as the data1 has 2 of (2,8). This is not required for the task. The required output here should be the "exact intersection of two df", i.e. as the (2,8) should appear only once just like other common entries, (4,6) and (5,6). This will lead to the correct count of 3 common rows in both df.

Similar thing is also observed when the input is:

```
# input df's
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[1,2,3,4,5,2],                    
                      'x3':[9,8,7,6,6,8]})

data3 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[2,1,2,2,4,4,5],                   
                      'x3':[8,3,9,8,7,6,6]})
```

Here, both data1 and data3 has two instances of (2,8). So the **required output** should be a total of **4 common rows** (with 2 instances of (2,8) and one each of (4,6) and (5,6)). Instead, the current logic gets 4 instances of (2,8)!!!

```
   x1  x3 _merge
1   2   8   both
2   2   8   both
3   2   8   both
4   2   8   both
6   4   6   both
7   5   6   both
count: 6
```

If anyone can help me fix this issue in the logic that will be greatly appreciated. Any alternative suggestion/feedback are also welcomed. :)

Cheers!

Comment: The method "[drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)" can help.

Comment: Actually not! As shown in the second example, if there are two instances of (2,8) in both data1 and data3, the required output should also have 2 instances. I believe "drop_duplicates" will only have the unique common rows not the exact intersection which required in this case. Anyways appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I oversaw this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge will do cartesian product if there are duplicated values in the join columns. To avoid this, you can create a dummy count column to deduplicate before merging. Use the last case as an example:

```
data1['cnt'] = data1.groupby(data1.columns.tolist()).x1.cumcount()
data3['cnt'] = data3.groupby(data3.columns.tolist()).x1.cumcount()

data1.merge(data3, how='inner')
   x1  x3  cnt
0   2   8    0
1   4   6    0
2   5   6    0
3   2   8    1
```

Comment: Appreciate your response. If possible can you please elaborate on what you mean by deduplicate here? The end goal is to get the count of common rows/ exact intersection of both dataframes.

Comment: Yeah, the count is zero based, but it should work the same way -